# C++ Compiled Headers receiving tons of errors

Tags: c++

I am receiving errors like cout is undeclared identifier

I have gone through MULTIPLE times and there is nothing I can see that I have done wrong! I am knew so please be patient.

I have checked everything multiple times and this just does not make since to me.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include "add.h"


int main()
{
    std::cout << "this will call function which will have you type in numbers which when done will call the second function as well as giving the second function answers to what it needs. " << '\n';

    int numOne{ function() };
    int numTwo{ function() };
    std::cout << "With those two numbers we can add them! and our answer is!" << functionTwo(numOne, numTwo) << '\n';
    std::cout << "we now sent functionTwo the numbers we made using function for simplness. Now functionTwo can have the numbers it needs to do what it needs to do." << '\n';


    // This code will make it not close automatically.
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

add.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

int functionTwo(int a, int b)

{
    std::cout << " fdsaf dasf dsa" << '\n';


    std::cout << 2 * a << '\n';
    std::cout << 2 + b << '\n';
    int c{ 2 + b };
    int d{ 2 * a };



    return c + d;

}
```

add2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"
int function()

{
    int a{ 0 };
    std::cin >> a;
    return a;

}
```

add.h

```
#ifndef _IOSTREAM_
#define _IOSTREAM_

int function();



int functionTwo(int a, int b);



#endif
```

I am using Microsoft Visual studio and I am trying to compile this. I made sure to make new items / the .cpp files and the .h file. I have tried deleteing the pch.h and the pch.cpp files but I just don't understand what I am doing wrong. Please help me. I am knew so I am sorry for that.

Comment: We don't want to know what the errors are "like". We want to know what the errors "are".

Comment: You say you're using PCH? Which headers are precompiled and which files are used to create the PCH? When asking for help with errors you're receiving, it would seem like a good idea to also post the actual errors you're receiving… ;-)

Comment: Also, just a minor note: This will almost certainly not be the cause of your issues, but `_IOSTREAM_` is not a valid identifier to use in a C++ program. Anything that starts with an `_` followed by an uppercase letter (also: anything that contains a double underscore) is a reserved name that programs are not allowed to use.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, you should not be using `_IOSTREAM_` as your include guard for "add.h", that is the exact guard used in the `iostream` header. Uses something like `__ADD_H__` or since you are using VS you can use `#pragma once`

Comment: If Visual Studio PCH, where are your stdafx.h includes?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor oh wow, you're right. This may be the first time I've ever see the use of a reserved name in an include guard to actually have made things blow up…

Comment: im recieving errors like

Comment: Further explanation of what Chris Taylor and Michael Kenzel are talking about: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Very poor question as you don't tell us what errors you get.

Comment: @Annonymous don't even waste your time trying to get the error messages to not looks like jumbled garbage in a comment. Paste the error messages into the question and surround it with `<pre></pre>`. You will also have an easier time getting the error messages from the Output tab. The Error List leaves out too much information and doesn't format to text well at all.

Comment: Just as another note on @ChrisTaylor's comment: You also shouldn't use `__ADD_H__` as that is a reserved name as well. Personally, I use something like, e.g., `INCLUDED_ADD_H`. Having all include guards follow the same naming scheme has the added advantage of not cluttering your autocomplete suggestions all over the place…

Comment: Why people have this mystical belief in the powers of the underscore, I will never know - my further thoughts: https://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/letter-the-second/

Comment: Underscores taste *amazing* with an artichoke dip.

Comment: 1>c:\users\cde\desktop\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\add.cpp(8): error C2039: 'cout': is not a member of 'std'
1>c:\users\cde\desktop\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\predefined c++ types (compiler internal)(256): note: see declaration of 'std'

Comment: there are a ton more like this.

Comment: can someone help?

Comment: And you get these errors with the order of `#include` directives exactly like you showed in your code above?

Answer (score -1):

What you do is add:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "add.h"
```

so in each one that uses the header add.h make sure that above it you also use the pch.h otherwise it will tell you did you forget to use it and it will not work. Simply adding `#include "pch.h"`
fixed it all.